# Is there any format-prolongation encryption?

Tags: encryption

Given plaintext $m$ of length $l_m = |m| > 0$ 
After encryption $E$
$$E(m) = c$$
we receive a cipher $c$ with an elongated length $l_c = |c| > |m|$  
With decryption $D$
$$D(c) = D(E(m)) = m$$
we receive $m$ again.

The opposite does not to be always true:
$$E(D(m)) = m' \text{ } \text{ with } \text{ } m' \in \\{m,m'',m''',...\\}$$

Are there any encryption methods similar to this? Do they have some proper name?

---

- Computation time for $E$ and $D$ should be similar
- $E$ and $D$ are allowed to have keys which can also be different as long the opposite key can be computed if everything else is known
- the elongation does not need to be constant length but most likely smaller than 4 bytes (in rare cases no elongation is also allowed)
- every bitstring of suitable length can be used by $E$ and $D$, to be less strict let's say at least 10% of them, need to be detectable if it is working or not

Comment: All randomized encryption algorithms produce ciphertexts that are longer than the plaintext. If not, the scheme can't satisfy even the most basic security property.

Comment: @Mikero Thanks for reply. I'm new to randomized encryption. According to my search results the basic idea is to add some random pattern before encryption and remove it after decryption. Common encryption methods like AES should be compatible with it. However for e.g. AES128 the prolongation would be one block size of 128bits. Is there any randomized encryption method which only extends by 32bit or even shorter? (less byte is better)

Comment: If ciphertext expansion is $k$ bis, then CPA security can be broken with $2^{k/2}$ effort, so shorter expansion is a bad idea. You might want to investigate nonce-based encryption. It can be deterministic and have no ciphertext expansion. You just need access to some agreed upon non-repeating value to use as the nonce.

Comment: If I understood it correctly if e.g. $k=16$ and we extend our 128-bit $m$ to a 144-bit $c$ during the encryption we can find in $2^8$ steps the $k$ used random bit extension. But is this also the case if we use some method with an extra key of larger size (e.g. similar to $|m|$)?

Comment: nonces or Initialization vectors can also work if they are allowed to expand in size and if they are not symmetric and their relation is similar safe as the relation in between $m$ and $c$

Comment: @UncleBob: what Mikero referred to when talking about breaking CPA security with $2^{k/2}$ effort is that if you submit the same plaintext to encrypt $2^{k/2}$ times, then with good probability two of the ciphertexts will be exactly the same (allowing you to distinguish the encryption scheme from a random function).

Comment: @poncho Thanks, forgot about that. Target $m$ are supposed to be different and with this collision chance around $2^{|m|/2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed AES can be used after adding some extra (randomized) bits. Thanks for the hint!
We start with a 128-bit message and add $n$ extra (random) bits at the end of it.
We first apply AES to the last 128 bit (which include those $n$ bit added) and than apply it a 2nd time to the first 128 bit.
If it surpass 256 bit we apply it 3 times and so on.
Decryption in reverse order.

Only downside is 128-bit is the smallest size. Min message size could be $128-n$.
However it can't get much smaller without losing security.